# Generate XSLT for XML Infopath Form

Tags: xml, xslt, infopath

I need help on converting Infopath XML to XSLT its very challenging for me to convert. Can anyone help me on creating XSLT for the below XML.
This is an Infopath form i need help in creating Stylesheet for the xml which are created using the form library.

I tried to create XSLT but all gone in vein.

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <?mso-infoPathSolution name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:Project-Setup:-myXSD-2018-03-14T07-59-16" solutionVersion="1.0.0.1013" productVersion="15.0.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" ?>
            <?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.3"?>
            <my:myFields>
                <my:RequestNo>ak123</my:RequestNo>
                <my:LOB>FA</my:LOB>
                <my:AreaFinMgr>

                <pc:Person xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls"><pc:DisplayName>FM</pc:DisplayName><pc:AccountId>i:0#.w|ad\fm</pc:AccountId><pc:AccountType>User</pc:AccountType></pc:Person></my:AreaFinMgr>
                <my:ProjMgr>

                <pc:Person xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls"><pc:DisplayName>NT</pc:DisplayName><pc:AccountId>i:0#.w|ad\nt</pc:AccountId><pc:AccountType>User</pc:AccountType></pc:Person></my:ProjMgr>
                <my:Approver>

                <pc:Person xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls"><pc:DisplayName>AT</pc:DisplayName><pc:AccountId>i:0#.w|ad\at</pc:AccountId><pc:AccountType>User</pc:AccountType></pc:Person></my:Approver>
                <my:InternalUse>
                    <my:PSStatus>Completed</my:PSStatus>
                    <my:PSComments></my:PSComments>
                    <my:PSby>
                        <pc:Person>
                            <pc:DisplayName>i:0#.w|ad\ga</pc:DisplayName>
                            <pc:AccountId></pc:AccountId>
                            <pc:AccountType></pc:AccountType>
                        </pc:Person>
                    </my:PSby>
                    <my:PSDate>2019-02-12</my:PSDate>
                    <my:Prod_by>
                        <pc:Person>
                            <pc:DisplayName>i:0#.w|ad\nr</pc:DisplayName>
                            <pc:AccountId></pc:AccountId>
                            <pc:AccountType></pc:AccountType>
                        </pc:Person>
                    </my:Prod_by>
                    <my:Prod_Date>2019-02-12</my:Prod_Date>
                </my:InternalUse>
                <my:Repeating>
                    <my:Item>
                        <my:RequestTYpe>1</my:RequestTYpe>
                        <my:RequestText>New Request</my:RequestText>
                        <my:NewSection>
                            <my:New>Project</my:New>
                            <my:Tier1>R</my:Tier1>
                            <my:Tier2>RAProj</my:Tier2>
                            <my:Tier3>RAMIn</my:Tier3>
                            <my:Tier4>RAM_N_P</my:Tier4>
                            <my:Tier5>RNUR</my:Tier5>
                            <my:Tier6></my:Tier6>
                            <my:Tier7></my:Tier7>
                            <my:Parent>RNUR</my:Parent>
                            <my:NIPP>ATRev</my:NIPP>
                            <my:PPC>XX1528</my:PPC>
                            <my:SpecialInstruction>Use project XX1528</my:SpecialInstruction>
                            <my:BudgetCode></my:BudgetCode>
                            <my:WorkType></my:WorkType>
                            <my:CAPPMLOB></my:CAPPMLOB>
                            <my:OpenTimeEntry></my:OpenTimeEntry>
                            <my:ClaritySpecialInst></my:ClaritySpecialInst>
                            <my:ITROI_StartDate xsi:nil="true"></my:ITROI_StartDate>
                            <my:ITROI_EndDate xsi:nil="true"></my:ITROI_EndDate>
                            <my:ITROI_Desc></my:ITROI_Desc>
                            <my:ITROI_RMC></my:ITROI_RMC>
                            <my:ITROI_IsProgIni>No</my:ITROI_IsProgIni>
                            <my:Temp1>
                                <pc:Person>
                                    <pc:DisplayName></pc:DisplayName>
                                    <pc:AccountId></pc:AccountId>
                                    <pc:AccountType></pc:AccountType>
                                </pc:Person>
                            </my:Temp1>
                            <my:Temp3></my:Temp3>
                            <my:Temp4>
                                <pc:Person>
                                    <pc:DisplayName></pc:DisplayName>
                                    <pc:AccountId></pc:AccountId>
                                    <pc:AccountType></pc:AccountType>
                                </pc:Person>
                            </my:Temp4>
                            <my:Temp5>
                                <pc:Person>
                                    <pc:DisplayName></pc:DisplayName>
                                    <pc:AccountId></pc:AccountId>
                                    <pc:AccountType></pc:AccountType>
                                </pc:Person>
                            </my:Temp5>
                            <my:field2></my:field2>
                            <my:EPMOVali>false</my:EPMOVali>
                            <my:Capitalization xsi:nil="true"></my:Capitalization>
                        </my:NewSection>
                        <my:DescChange>
                            <my:DescNew></my:DescNew>
                            <my:DescIPP></my:DescIPP>
                            <my:DescName></my:DescName>
                            <my:DescNewName></my:DescNewName>
                            <my:DescSpecial></my:DescSpecial>
                        </my:DescChange>
                        <my:Rollup>
                            <my:RollNew></my:RollNew>
                            <my:RollIPP></my:RollIPP>
                            <my:RollNewLoc></my:RollNewLoc>
                            <my:RollSpecial></my:RollSpecial>
                        </my:Rollup>
                    </my:Item>
                </my:Repeating>
                <my:ClickStatus>PPC_Created</my:ClickStatus>
                <my:listName>1</my:listName>
                <my:formName></my:formName>
                <my:ReasonForRequest>Projt</my:ReasonForRequest>
                <my:EPMO_Field>false</my:EPMO_Field>
                <my:LOB_PMO></my:LOB_PMO>
                <my:Billable>Yes</my:Billable>
            </my:myFields>
```

Request No  LOB PSStatus    New Parent  NIPP    PPC
ak123   FA  Completed   Project RNUR    ATRev   XX1528

This is what i tried

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:template match="/">
            <html> 
            <body>
              <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
              <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                  <th style="text-align:left">Request No</th>
                  <th style="text-align:left">LOB</th>
                  <th style="text-align:left">PSStatus</th>
                  <th style="text-align:left">New Parent</th>
                  <th style="text-align:left">NIPP</th>
                  <th style="text-align:left">PPC</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="my:myFields/my:Repeating">
                <tr>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="my:myFields/my:RequestNo" /></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="my:myFields/my:LOB"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="my:myFields/my:InternalUse/my:PSStatus"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="my:myFields/my:Repeating/my:Item"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="my:myFields/my:Repeating/my:Item/my:NIPP"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="my:myFields/my:Repeating/my:Item/my:PPC"/></td>
                </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </table>
            </body>
            </html>
            </xsl:template>
            </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Post your attempt so we can help you fix it. Otherwise you're just asking for someone to do your work for you.

Comment: Note also that your input uses a `my:` prefix without binding it to a namespace, which is not allowed.

Comment: Hi @michael-hor257k Please find my updated comments

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment to your question, your input is not a well-formed XML document and cannot be processed by XSLT.

If you had a well-formed XML input such as:

**XML**

```
<my:myFields xmlns:my="http://example.com/my" xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <my:RequestNo>ak123</my:RequestNo>
  <my:LOB>FA</my:LOB>
  <my:AreaFinMgr>
    <pc:Person>
      <pc:DisplayName>FM</pc:DisplayName>
      <pc:AccountId>i:0#.w|ad\fm</pc:AccountId>
      <pc:AccountType>User</pc:AccountType>
    </pc:Person>
  </my:AreaFinMgr>
  <my:ProjMgr>
    <pc:Person>
      <pc:DisplayName>NT</pc:DisplayName>
      <pc:AccountId>i:0#.w|ad\nt</pc:AccountId>
      <pc:AccountType>User</pc:AccountType>
    </pc:Person>
  </my:ProjMgr>
  <my:Approver>
    <pc:Person>
      <pc:DisplayName>AT</pc:DisplayName>
      <pc:AccountId>i:0#.w|ad\at</pc:AccountId>
      <pc:AccountType>User</pc:AccountType>
    </pc:Person>
  </my:Approver>
  <my:InternalUse>
    <my:PSStatus>Completed</my:PSStatus>
    <my:PSComments/>
    <my:PSby>
      <pc:Person>
        <pc:DisplayName>i:0#.w|ad\ga</pc:DisplayName>
        <pc:AccountId/>
        <pc:AccountType/>
      </pc:Person>
    </my:PSby>
    <my:PSDate>2019-02-12</my:PSDate>
    <my:Prod_by>
      <pc:Person>
        <pc:DisplayName>i:0#.w|ad\nr</pc:DisplayName>
        <pc:AccountId/>
        <pc:AccountType/>
      </pc:Person>
    </my:Prod_by>
    <my:Prod_Date>2019-02-12</my:Prod_Date>
  </my:InternalUse>
  <my:Repeating>
    <my:Item>
      <my:RequestTYpe>1</my:RequestTYpe>
      <my:RequestText>New Request</my:RequestText>
      <my:NewSection>
        <my:New>Project</my:New>
        <my:Tier1>R</my:Tier1>
        <my:Tier2>RAProj</my:Tier2>
        <my:Tier3>RAMIn</my:Tier3>
        <my:Tier4>RAM_N_P</my:Tier4>
        <my:Tier5>RNUR</my:Tier5>
        <my:Tier6/>
        <my:Tier7/>
        <my:Parent>RNUR</my:Parent>
        <my:NIPP>ATRev</my:NIPP>
        <my:PPC>XX1528</my:PPC>
        <my:SpecialInstruction>Use project XX1528</my:SpecialInstruction>
        <my:BudgetCode/>
        <my:WorkType/>
        <my:CAPPMLOB/>
        <my:OpenTimeEntry/>
        <my:ClaritySpecialInst/>
        <my:ITROI_StartDate xsi:nil="true"/>
        <my:ITROI_EndDate xsi:nil="true"/>
        <my:ITROI_Desc/>
        <my:ITROI_RMC/>
        <my:ITROI_IsProgIni>No</my:ITROI_IsProgIni>
        <my:Temp1>
          <pc:Person>
            <pc:DisplayName/>
            <pc:AccountId/>
            <pc:AccountType/>
          </pc:Person>
        </my:Temp1>
        <my:Temp3/>
        <my:Temp4>
          <pc:Person>
            <pc:DisplayName/>
            <pc:AccountId/>
            <pc:AccountType/>
          </pc:Person>
        </my:Temp4>
        <my:Temp5>
          <pc:Person>
            <pc:DisplayName/>
            <pc:AccountId/>
            <pc:AccountType/>
          </pc:Person>
        </my:Temp5>
        <my:field2/>
        <my:EPMOVali>false</my:EPMOVali>
        <my:Capitalization xsi:nil="true"/>
      </my:NewSection>
      <my:DescChange>
        <my:DescNew/>
        <my:DescIPP/>
        <my:DescName/>
        <my:DescNewName/>
        <my:DescSpecial/>
      </my:DescChange>
      <my:Rollup>
        <my:RollNew/>
        <my:RollIPP/>
        <my:RollNewLoc/>
        <my:RollSpecial/>
      </my:Rollup>
    </my:Item>
  </my:Repeating>
  <my:ClickStatus>PPC_Created</my:ClickStatus>
  <my:listName>1</my:listName>
  <my:formName/>
  <my:ReasonForRequest>Projt</my:ReasonForRequest>
  <my:EPMO_Field>false</my:EPMO_Field>
  <my:LOB_PMO/>
  <my:Billable>Yes</my:Billable>
</my:myFields>
```

then you could use:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="http://example.com/my"
exclude-result-prefixes="my">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html> 
        <body>
            <h2>put your own title here</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                <th>Request No</th>
                <th>LOB</th>
                <th>PSStatus</th>
                <th>New Parent</th>
                <th>NIPP</th>
                <th>PPC</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="my:myFields/my:Repeating">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="../my:RequestNo" /></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="..//my:LOB"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="../my:InternalUse/my:PSStatus"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="my:Item/my:NewSection/my:New"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="my:Item/my:NewSection/my:NIPP"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="my:Item/my:NewSection/my:PPC"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

**Result**

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>put your own title here</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Request No</th>
<th>LOB</th>
<th>PSStatus</th>
<th>New Parent</th>
<th>NIPP</th>
<th>PPC</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ak123</td>
<td>FA</td>
<td>Completed</td>
<td>Project</td>
<td>ATRev</td>
<td>XX1528</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the namespace handling in the `xsl:stylesheet` open tag.

Comment: Hi @michael-hor257k this is an infopath form which is auto generated from Sharepoint. Thanks for your answer i will check and let you know.

Comment: @Fshbet It doesn't matter how it's generated; it is not a well-formed XML document and it will be rejected by every conforming XML parser: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq5U